# Remote Desktop login not working with SBS 2011

Tags: remote-desktop

I am using an SBS 2011. Using the SBS console, I made a user a member of Windows SBS Remote Web Access Users, and gave permission to logon that user's computer using Remote Desktop as a local administrator.(client machine is running Windows 7) 
When they try to connect, they get a message as follows. "To log on to this remote computer, you must be granted the Allow log on through Terminal Services right. By default, members of the Remote Desktop Users group have this right...etc etc"

I have gone back and made sure that the user is a member of the remote desktop users. Even as the administrator I am not able to connect to this particular computer. Other users are able to connect to their computers though. Any ideas as to what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are they listed in the allow list where you enabled remote desktop in Computer->Properties->Remote->Select users.  If I recall, the remote desktop group is more commonly use for Terminal Servers.  If you are using this for admin, then you will likely have to put them in the remote desktop GUI.